# What's the mistake?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a page with some Javascript code:

```
    function createNewWindow () {
      var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
      var newPage = "<html><head><title>";
      newPage += userName;
      newPage += "</title></head><body>";
      newPage += "<p>Hello " + userName;
      newPage += "</p></body></html>";
      var j = window.open('');
     j.document.write(newPage);
     j.document.close();
     }
```

Now dreamweaver says there is an mistake at lines:

```
  var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value
  var newPage = "<html><head><title>"
```

I don't see the mistake and I searched the whole internet. Someone here to help me?

Comment: Does Dreamweaver dislike missing `;`? (I know _I_ do)

Comment: .. Although JavaScript will automatically insert `;` for you, they aren't really _optional_.

Comment: *"I searched the whole internet"* ... that made me chuckle.

Comment: @Amine: A semi-colon?

Comment: 3 semicolumns are missing.

Comment: That's not the mistake.. I fixed it and it still gives an error

Comment: Did you actually run the code? I'm not saying Dreamweaver is wrong or  an inferior IDE...

Comment: @user2177152: And the error message isn't more specific? If it can't name the mistake, there is none.

Comment: No, if I want to run it in the browser Dreamweaver says the error must be fixed before running the code

Comment: Well, according to my jsFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/Lfahe/), your code works fine. Maybe Dreamweaver does not like the tags in the string. So, the answer the your original question might be *"you are using Dreamweaver"* ( `;)` )

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it in Sublime Text and it worked. I still don't understand it..

Comment: I see it, the line: var newPage = "<html><head><title>";  is edited by someone, the real mistake was that I did ' ' and ". On my computer they look pretty similar. Sorry for this stupid mistake, I'm only 15 alright?

Comment: @Bergi : I meant ";" ....an embarrassing typo

Answer (score 1):

Your code is syntactically correct. If DW is complaining, it's about the lack of semi-colons:

```
function createNewWindow() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value; // semi-colon here
    var newPage = "<html><head><title>"; // semi-colon here
    newPage += userName;
    newPage += "</title></head><body>";
    newPage += "<p>Hello " + userName;
    newPage += "</p></body></html>";
    var j = window.open(''); // semi-colon here
    j.document.write(newPage);
    j.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed a semicolon at :

```
var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value
var newPage = "<html><head><title>"
var j = window.open('')
```

No ?

Does it work with :

```
var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
var newPage = "<html><head><title>";
var j = window.open('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the missing semicolons

```
var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
var newPage = "<html><head><title>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `;`:

```
 var userName = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
 var newPage = "<html><head><title>";
```

Comment: that's not it, it still doesn't works